# Eclipse Error "Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete ArgumentList"

Tags: java

I keep getting this error message:

Error: Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete ArgumentList

How should I fix it?
inserting other words because stackoverflow won't let me post this otherwise

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*; 

public class javahw5_11
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

    int saleData[] = new int[5];  

    System.out.print("How many shares are you buying?"); 
    saleData[0] = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("What is the purchase price per share?"); 
    saleData[1] = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("How much was the sales price per share?"); 
    saleData[2] = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("How much is the purchase commission?"); 
    saleData[3] = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("How much was the sales commission?"); 
    saleData[4] = keyboard.nextInt(); 

    double profit = getProfit(saleData[]); 
    System.out.print("Your profit is "+profit); 

    keyboard.close(); 
  }

  public static double getProfit(int saleData[])
  {
    double profit = (((saleData[0]*saleData[2])-saleData[4])-((saleData[0]*saleData[1])+saleData[3]));
    return profit; 
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you think `getProfit(saleData[])` does and why do you think so?

Comment: don't place brackets after variable. just do like this: double profit = getProfit(saleData);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note `salesData[3]`. `salesData` doesn't exist. change it to `saleData`.

Note also `double profit = getProfit(saleData[]);`. remove the brackets from `saleData` as you are passing it as a **parameter**.

Answer (score 0):

Few mistakes.

1.) change `double profit = getProfit(saleData[]);` to `double profit = getProfit(saleData);`. Just need gto pass reference `saleData`

2.) use saleData instead `salesData` in `double profit = (((saleData[0] * saleData[2]) - saleData[4]) - ((saleData[0] * saleData[1]) + salesData[3]));`

Answer (score 0):

change it to below statement.. you have given as salesData[3] in your code

double profit = (((saleData[0]*saleData[2])-saleData[4])-((saleData[0]*saleData[1])+saleData[3]));